# Does order not matter in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, computer-science, regular-language, automata

I was looking at the question posed in this stackoverflow link ([Regular expression for odd number of a's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902496/regular-expression-for-odd-number-of-as)) for which it is asked to find the regular expression for strings that have odd number of `a` over `Σ = {a,b}`.

The answer given by the top comment which works is `b*(ab*ab*)*ab*`.

I am quite confused - `a` was placed just before the last `b*`, does this ordering actually matter? Why can't it be `b*a(ab*ab*)*b*` instead (where `a` is placed after the first `b*`), or any other permutation of it?

Another thing I am confused about is why it is `(ab*ab*)*` and not `(b*ab*ab*)*`. Isn't `b*ab*ab*` the more accurate definition of 'having exactly 2 `a`'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't it be `b*a(ab*ab*)*b*` instead?

`b*a(ab*ab*)*b*` does not work because it would require the string to have two consecutive `a`s before the first non-leading `b`, wouldn't it? For example, `abaa` would not be matched by your proposed regex when it should. Use the regex debugger on a site like [Regex101](https://regex101.com) to see this for yourself.

On the other hand, moving the whole `ab*` part to the start (`b*ab*(ab*ab*)*`) works as well.

> why it is `(ab*ab*)*` and not `(b*ab*ab*)*`?

`(b*ab*ab*)*` *does work*, but the first `b*` is quite redundant because whatever `b` there is left, will be matched by the last `b*` in the group. There is also a `b*` before the group, which causes the `b*` to not be able to match anything, hence it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many equivalent regular expressions which generate a given (infinite) regular language. A particular expression might be preferable in some cases and by certain authors: one might prefer a minimal expression, or one which shows structure or symmetry, or even one that simplifies the reasoning in a proof by induction.

Your particular suggestion to move the a is insufficient since, as noted above, that ensures the substring aa will appear in any string with more than one a. However, ab*ab* could be changed to b*ab*a to make that placement work. Choosing b*ab*ab* would work with either placement. You could even go for an expression like b*ab* + b*ab*ab*ab* + (b*ab*ab*)a(b*ab*ab*) which might be nice to work with depending on your application. Something like b*(ab*ab*)ab* has the advantage of being minimal (if it's not strictly minimal, it must be pretty close).